# How is this OpenPGP key displaying in a non hexedecimal format?

Tags: encryption, pgp, gnupg, decryption

Looking at [a GnuPG manual on openskills](http://wiki.openskills.org/OpenSkills/GPG+Signing+and+Encrypting), I notice that the main key id `GEBV933F` is in a different format than the usual hexadecimal (`G` is no hexadecimal digit).

How is this done?

Comment: I suspect it's been Base64 encoded. Perhaps an attribute of the mail server the message was sent via.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr:** these are made up key IDs of somebody trying to hide the actual information. They're not valid OpenPGP key IDs.

### OpenPGP Key IDs

Following [RFC 4880, OpenPGP, 3.3 Key IDs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.3), a

> Key ID is an eight-octet scalar that identifies a key.

[12.2 Key IDs and Fingerprints](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-12.2) further specifies the calculation, but again no *representation* of those lower 64 bits to be used. Often, 32 bit values ("short key IDs") are used in practice. An example describes pretty well how the key IDs are related:

```
fingerprint: 0D69 E11F 12BD BA07 7B37  26AB 4E1F 799A A4FF 2279 (160 bits)
long id:                                    4E1F 799A A4FF 2279  (64 bits)
short id:                                             A4FF 2279  (32 bits)
```

`XAF476E9` and `GEBV933F` form weird key IDs. They can't be hexadecimal, which wouldn't allow `X` and `G`. They're probably using a digit range matching pretty much including all decimal digits plus letters up to X, which means eight digit numbers would allow to store about `ld(36^8) ~= 41` bits -- not enough for a more compact representation of (long) key IDs.

### Digging Deeper

Well, you don't really need to dig deep. Let's assume the documentation was written by somebody using *real* keys, who at the same time tries to hide his identity and either has a bad understanding of key IDs, or wants to reveal manipulation of the key IDs to the skilled eye.

The quoted manual also provides examples of encoded signatures. Let's have a look at those! A string `This is some text.` gets signed, probably using the author's key. And we also get the quoted result, which the author stored as `test.txt.asc`:

> The signed version will look something like this:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
> Hash: SHA1
>
> This is some text.
>
> -----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
> Version: GnuPG v1.2.1 (GNU/Linux)
> Comment: 'Email me for my public key'
>
> iD8DBQE+ycRnF1uP4b67kz8RArZdAJ9e98RkcYICyJktEpah5/RoQX93vgCfUuOh
> 1I3aTPTGXitruRjhms3Kx7Y=
> =ju77
> -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
> ```

The output showing the weird key IDs actually verifies a signature of exactly this file:

> ```
> [you@tiger]$ gpg --verify test.txt.asc 
> gpg: Signature made Tue 20 May 2003 04:00:07 PM EST using DSA key ID GEBV933F
> gpg: Good signature from "fbloggs@openskills.com"
> ```

Now, what happens if we run this on our own?

```
gpg: Signature made Tue May 20 08:00:07 2003 CEST
gpg:                using DSA key BEBB933F
gpg: Good signature from "[uid removed]"
gpg:                 aka "[uid removed]"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 3318 D8EC 1EAD 3771 3B54  2893 175B 8FE1 BEBB 933F
```

*I removed the user ID as the user might have tried to stay anonymous. I didn't care about his key ID/fingerprint, as he indeed posted it anyway and everybody can query the information if he wants.*

Surprised about a close-match of the key IDs?

```
   real key ID: BEBB933F
claimed key ID: GEBV933F
```

Obviously, the two non-hexadecimal digits have been scrambled. Now, what about `XAF476E9`?

```
$ gpg --list-keys BEBB933F
pub   1024D/BEBB933F 2003-04-09
uid                            [uid removed]
uid                            [uid removed]
sub   1024g/CAC476E9 2003-04-09
```

A new subkey! Again comparing the keys:

```
   real key ID: CAC476E9
claimed key ID: XAF476E9
```

Again, two digits differ.

Comment: Ok, very interesting. I asked because of the tweet snowden made about the fake ISIS encrypted message. I noticed the key id contained an O and a H. I'm going write an article about this, and will drop a link to your answer. All we can assume from here is that the publisher of the image has purposely created a fake key? Although for what purpose because the message was already decrypted.

Comment: You can't say whether he created a fake key or not, but you _can_ say somebody faked GnuPG's output. Just out of curiosity: did anybody send the text in the video through some OCR software and have a look at what's in there? ;)

Comment: Searching for the first few characters, you can find a dump of questionable quality. After fixing some obvious problems, one can actually print the OpenPGP headers through `pgpdump` (and other people also did that already). I don't provide links here as I didn't further verify those documents.

Comment: Pretty much at the same time you posted, another similar question specific to the (proclaimed) ISIS video was posted: http://security.stackexchange.com/q/111698/19837 -- I added some more thoughts on the video over there.

Comment: Awesome stuff. Your answers helped me understand so much. I am going to play about with sending the video through OCR software as it sounds very interesting and something I've never done before.

Comment: I quoted a reference with the data (which still need verification with the video, given the contents of the video are not faked either) in the other question I linked. If my post answered your question, consider accepting it (have a look at the [FAQ]  for details).